# how do i alter the file field 'file maximum size upload' value using hook_form_alter in drupal 6?

Tags: entities, 6, files

In drupal 6 project,I need to alter all file fields 'file maximum size upload' value using hook_form_alter.I have created a custom module and used '#after_build' in hook_form_alter() to alter the default value.

```
function my_custom_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){      

if (isset($form['type']) && isset($form['#node']) && $form['type']['#value'] . '_node_form' == $form_id) {
    // attach our #after_build handler so we can modify cck fields
    $form['#after_build'][] = 'my_custom_module_after_build';
}
```

}

and the callback function for '#after_build' is

```
function my_custom_module_after_build($form, &$form_state){
    $fields = filefield_get_field_list($form['type']['#value']);
    if (!empty($fields)) {
        $fields_name = array_keys($fields);
        //dsm($fields_name);
        foreach ($fields_name as $field_name) {
            $value=100;
            $form['#field_info']['$field_name']['widget']['max_filesize_per_file']=$value.'MB';
         }
     } 
     return $form;
}
```

but it doesn't alter the default value.please tell me how can i alter that value?

Comment: You do know that the value is pulled from php.ini, right? More specifically, the value is the same as php.ini's `upload_max_filesize` value. I'm not sure that altering via the hook will do you any good. It will most likely just confuse your users.

Comment: Actually what i need is to alter the default value of maximum file size of all file field which will be set in those file field settings form by administrator. For example,let us consider a one file field in which admin set its maximum file size upload=3MB and then what i need is to alter that value(3MB) by my custom module.I tried by above method but i coudn't able to alter it.